# Filling Python panda dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I can write a regular dataframe which has values for rows and columns, however, cant' find a way to write the rows with one entry for e.g. method1, method2..etc, deterministic..). And, also I haven't found a way to split a column ( for e.g. no of bits | 4 ).

This is a single excel file where data will be appended after some interval. Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Include the excel file and desired output.

Comment: If you create another worksheet that references your worksheet in a "flatter" format it'll save you a lot of headaches. You could process it in python, but it'll be a PITA.

Comment: @MYGz I have updated the post and added the files hyperlink at the beginning of the text

Comment: Sorry, i guess there are some permission issues with tthe desired output file, i will check it and update once done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would be easier to use xlwt (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) than DataFrame.to_excel when the excel file is formatted like yours. With xlwt you can specify cells in the worksheet and then write whatever you like to them.

Comment: Thanks. I will explore xlwt :)

Comment: I tried xlwt and it served my purpose. Thanks for the advice :)